# Can "nor" be used after "and"? As in "and nor"?

Tags: word-usage

I came across this post on Facebook:

> "Well, if it makes you feel any better..."
>
> It doesn't, and nor do I
>   think you intended it to.

Can "nor" be used after "and" like that? Doesn't look right to me.

Personally, I would go with:

> It doesn't, nor do I think you intended it to.

Comment: I'm with you. Nix to *and nor*.

Comment: I believe in AmE, "and + nor" is not really acceptable. It's heard in BrE fairly often, though more so with "neither", as in _I doesn't, and neither do I think ..._

Comment: Perfectly commonplace and unremarkable to me. _Nor_ is semantically equivalent to _not… either_, and in cases where the latter would require a coordinator, that coordinator can be added before _nor_ as well. If it’s a _but_, it’s even required: “It’s not good, but not is it bad” really doesn’t work the same without _but_.

Comment: To this Brit, either form is acceptable. When spoken, I think the latter (without "and") requires a longer break/pause than does the *and* form.

Answer (score 2):

No.  "Nor" is a conjunction, like "and".  You wouldn't say "and and" or "but and"

Comment: Sorry, Bob, I made a typo. Here it is again: When combined with the coordinator "and", "nor" is best regarded as a connective adverb

Comment: In AmE, I gather it's rare. But in BrE it's heard sometimes, though "neither" is more common: _The Germans haven't replied and nor/neither have the French_.

Comment: This is the second time today that "(primarily UK)" has bit me in the butt.  :)  You're correct.

Comment: But ... but ... but ...!